# Ant migration tool edits package.xml?

Tags: metadata-api, ant, migration-tool

When I run the ant migration tool, it is editing my `package.xml` file. Weirdly, all it is doing is re-arranging it -- moving tags around -- but it concerns me because it doesn't seem like running the process should edit the configuration files at all.

Is this an expected behavior?

How do I prevent the ant migration tool from editing `package.xml`? Is there are reason I would want it to change `package.xml`?

I am keeping package.xml checked into version control, or else I wouldn't have noticed this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have anything to cite this, so not making it an answer. This is to be expected. After several years of deployments and VCS struggles, I've seen ANT re-order and update the package.xml after retrieve many times. I believe it orders it by type alphabetically. A positive of this is if you have two types with the same name it will merge them.

Comment: At first I didn't think it was alphabetizing, but now I realize it's ASCII alphabetizing -- putting all capital letters before all lower case letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If package.xml is the source, and is in the destination/retrieve folder, it'll be updated. Otherwise, if it's elsewhere, or it has a different name, it won't be.

This is a part of the metadata API, and not unique to the migration tool. The migration tool itself just unzips whatever the API returns.

Comment: Is it reasonable to just add `/path/to/retrieveTarget/package.xml` to the project's .gitignore and keep my `package.xml` in a different directory?

Comment: @NathanHinchey Maybe. Keep in mind that to *deploy*, your package.xml must contain all of the elements to deploy, which typically means you'll want to use the one you get back from a retrieve, or build your own.

Comment: When would the one I get from retrieve be different from the one I use for the retrieve?

Comment: @NathanHinchey Because of wild cards, misspelled/missing elements (warnings), different case-sensitive sorting of the named members or names. The API returns a very specific order.